# Сopy cells depending on values in another cell

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, concatenate

In Google Sheets I try to copy cells B2:B4 depending on values in other cells C2:C4. 
For example -  [example.xlsx](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xhpD1b2YlfvOsYJBP5e1mD-Y-kiPBT80) made in Excel.

But stuck and can't find a solution on how to do it in Google Sheets.

[image]

I will be very grateful for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(","; ARRAYFORMULA(REPT(SPLIT(
 INDIRECT("B2:B"&COUNTA(B2:B)+1); ",")&","; 
 INDIRECT("C2:C"&COUNTA(C2:C)+1)))); ","))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks, @user0! I gess, that  did everything right, but unfortunately  I've got #ERROR! [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1i3t83iFHFFz2z5ON-JNEo2YXGHvyA-xI)

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: @ChainEvroSmak answer updated

Comment: I've already shared my sheet. Here [link] (https://drive.google.com/open?id=18eJwz9TLZUqVkEIflCRDSb48cdN_Rw5xJErvt7tUnI4) @user0

Comment: and I already fixed the issue for you and updated the answer :)

Comment: Thank you very mach, @user0! You are my hero!  :)